# what adapters should i use for listfragment and what class they should extend

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, android-adapter

First of all i am a newbie.I am developing an app Which has a viewpager and fragments in it,but later i decided to put lists in the fragments so i had to change them into Listfragments so i had to change the adpaters a bit,and now its not working and now i am totally confused that which adapter should extend what.

initially i had a Viewpager adapter which extends fragmentpageadapter(should it extend any kind of listfragment pageadapter)

and i have another customadapter which extends base adapter(custom adapter because i want a custom listview in the fragments).
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` (and by extension `ListFragment`) doesn't care what your adapter is as long as it conforms to the `ListAdapter` interface, which yours does if it extends `BaseAdapter`. There are some other Adapter implementations in the SDK for simple use cases, you can explore them on your own or look at the ApiDemos sample application.

Similarly, `ViewPager` only cares that you provide it something that extends `PagerAdapter`, which `FragmentPagerAdapter` does.

Comment: ok thanx ......can you please tell how to add Listfragments??i know how to add fragments.(given below) but i don't know how to add Listfragments  

List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));